# Troubles installing ROS C turtle base

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am following step by step the directions reported on [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu) web page to install ROS Cturtle on Ubuntu 10.10. However, when I try to install the package (step 1.4), I received a message like:

*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-cturtle-base*

I also tried the other packages (ROS only and PR2), but I got the same message. Same thing if I click on the link suggested on the web page.

What am I doing wrong? I apologize if my question sounds very basic, but I am beginner with Linux and with programming in general.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,
George

**Update:**
Hi guys,

thank you for you reply. I don't know what to say... I tried to re-install everything yesterday (following carefully the directions), and I obtained the same result as before. I tried today, and I got a different error message (see below). I tried multiple times, but I obtained always the same result.

Why this difference? What did I do wrong now? I know that most likely it is my bad, but is it possible that there is some problems in the repository?

Thank you, George

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-cturtle-base : Depends: ros-cturtle-ros-tutorials (= 0.2.4-s1297126046~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1297208879~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-joystick-drivers-tutorials (= 1.4.0-s1297127970~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.2-s1295083305~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-joystick-drivers (= 1.2.2-s1295082139~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-ros (= 1.2.4-s1295078370~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-visualization (= 1.2.2-s1295084832~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-camera-drivers (= 1.2.8-s1297313372~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-vision-opencv (= 1.2.5-s1295082686~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-rx (= 0.0.1-s1295080202~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-image-pipeline (= 1.2.2-s1295083182~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-sound-drivers (= 1.2.0-s1295084310~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-simulator-stage (= 1.2.4-s1296091028~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-image-common (= 1.2.0-s1295082600~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1297390611~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-imu-drivers (= 1.2.1-s1295085951~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-ros-comm (= 0.0.1-s1295079424~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-visualization-common (= 1.2.0-s1295079570~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-physics-ode (= 1.2.8-s1295081168~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-laser-drivers (= 1.2.2-s1295088704~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-driver-common (= 1.2.3-s1295080314~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-common-msgs (= 1.2.2-s1295079109~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-image-transport-plugins (= 0.3.2-s1295412838~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-robot-model (= 1.2.4-s1295080382~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.0-s1295094317~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-laser-pipeline (= 1.0.2-s1295079467~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-roslisp-support (= 0.2.10-s1295093535~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo (= 1.2.8-s1295086047~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-geometry (= 1.2.0-s1295079275~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-common (= 1.2.2-s1295079175~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-diagnostics (= 1.2.5-s1295080247~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-cturtle-navigation (= 1.2.3-s1295080042~jaunty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

**Update:**
Hi everyone,

thanks a lot for your help on this issue; modifying *"etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list"* from 'jaunty' to 'maverick' worked on my lab machine! :)

Unfortunately I am having troubles installing ROS (diamondback) on my netbook now, and the issues seem to be of the same nature as before. More in details, when I type (following step by step and carefully the indications of [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu)):

*sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full*

I get the same error message as before:

*E: unable to locate package ros-diamondback-desktop-full*

So I checked the *"/etc/apt/sources.list.d"* folder, but I didn't find "*ros-latest.list*".  I didn't get any other error messages before this step, and I set Ubuntu repositories to allow "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse." Any suggestion about why this is happening? Do you think that the fact I am running Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition could be a problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9152/troubles-installing-ros-c-turtle-base/) by [George](https://answers.ros.org/users/160/george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you mangled the package sources.

Jaunty is not 10.10.

Can you check your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (or similar)?
It should say maverick and not jaunty.

If that is OK, what does
apt-cache policy ros-cturtle-base give you?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you ran "sudo apt-get update" before you tried to install the package?

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1